# Parcelable CharSequence vs Serializable String (Worth it? Measurements?)

Tags: java, android, string, serialization, parcelable

While digging through the JDK docs, I noticed that String in Java SE implements Serializable. With that in mind, I now assume that Strings (when used with Intents and Bundles) go to the destination through Serializable.

My question is mainly: Is a CharSequence subclass that implements Parcelable worth it? Does it have performance improvements? If so, can I measure this? I am currently working with an app that has a lot of Strings (some Strings large themselves for parsing).

Comment: I get that generally, the data transfer is faster when using Parcelable. I'm talking explicitly about implementing CharSequence.

Comment: `String` is a special case in Serialization. It is normally implemented via `DataOutput.writeUTF().` I doubt that you can improve on it.

Comment: Interesting. Are there any other exceptions to Serializable?

Comment: Several: `Class`, arrays, `ObjectStreamClass`.